# error when using st_intersects, in CPL_geos_binop(st_geometry(x), st_geometry(y), op, par, pattern : Evaluation error: IllegalArgumentException

Tags: r, gdal, r-sf, r-sp, rgdal

Wish to do intersect two LINESTRING in R.

```
nc1 = st_read(shp_file_1)
nc2 = st_read(shp_file_2)
```

The above steps are successful, shapefiles can be loaded in R.

```
res= st_intersects(nc1, nc2)
Error in CPL_geos_binop(st_geometry(x), st_geometry(y), op, par, pattern,  :
  Evaluation error: IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1 elements.
```

So, how to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked shapefile nc1 and found features having only 1 point per feature even they're `LINESTRING`.

Remove these 1-point `LINESTRING`, the `st_intersects` operation can be successful.

```
nc1$cnt2 = stringr::str_count(nc1$geometry, ",")
```

Here `cnt2` is a newly created `data.frame` column to store number of `","` in the `geometry` column. This can indicate the number of points per feacture.

```
library('dplyr')
nc3 = filter(nc1, cnt2>1)
```

We can either do:

```
res= st_intersects(nc3, nc2)
```

or:

```
res = st_join(nc3, nc2, join = st_intersects)
```

Comment: elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this issue. If you cast the object explicitly to the correct type it can often fix any strange geometry issues.

```
nc1 <- st_cast(nc1,  "LINESTRING")
```

Also always worth looking at st_is_valid and st_make_valid