# Error with terra::intersect afer using terra:buffer in R: IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1 elements

Tags: r, raster, terra

I am trying to use the command `terra:intersect` from the R package `terra`, but I have been getting an error that I don't quite understand: `Error: IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1 elements`. I am quite sure that the error is caused by using `terra:buffer` just before trying to use `terra:intersect`. I think so, because everything works fine (and the polygons are valid) for the other objects, but for the buffered object I get the above error message whenever I try to run `terra::instersect()`, `terra::as.polygons()`, or `terra::is.valid()`. I can plot the buffered object though.

I have posted my code below to make the issue reproducible. I would be thankful if anyone has any insights on how to solve that. I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61404151/error-when-using-st-intersects-in-cpl-geos-binopst-geometryx-st-geometryy) with a similar issue for the package `sf`, but I could not generalize their solution to my context with the `terra` package. Thanks for your help!

Get the data. To download CDL data on Linux using CropscapeR i need to do the below process (in Windows it is easier)

```
library(CropScapeR)
# Skip the SSL check
httr::set_config(httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
# Automatically generate a temporary path to save the data
tif_file <- tempfile(fileext = '.tif')
# Download the raster TIF file into specified path, also read into R
#This is Santa Barbara County in California
ST_CDL <- GetCDLData(aoi = '06083', year = 2021, type = 'f', save_path = tif_file) 
terra::writeRaster(ST_CDL, "ST_CDL.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
ST_CDL = terra::rast("ST_CDL.tif")
```

Here is the code I am trying to run

```
nat_lands_codes <- rbind(c(63, 63), c(64, 64), c(141, 141), c(142, 142), c(143, 143), c(152, 152))
ST_CDL_nat_lands <- terra::classify(ST_CDL, nat_lands_codes, others=NA)
   #I have to do this weird intermediate steps below when I am trying to classify
   #multiple crops at once (or at least that's how it worked for me)
aux <- c(1:62, 65:140, 144:151, 153:255)
aux <- t(t(aux))
crops_codes <- cbind(aux, aux)
ST_CDL_crop <- terra::classify(ST_CDL, crops_codes, others=NA)
#Buffer around the object with crops of interest
ST_CDL_nat_lands <- terra::as.polygons(ST_CDL_nat_lands)
ST_CDL_crop <- terra::as.polygons(ST_CDL_crop)
   #No need to run this, but if you run is.valid(ST_CDL_nat_lands)
   #is.valid(ST_CDL_crop), you will see the that the geometries are valid
   #ST_CDL is NAD83 (meters). I am reprojecting it to WGS84
ST_CDL_nat_lands <- terra::project(ST_CDL_nat_lands, "EPSG:4326")
ST_CDL_crop <- terra::project(ST_CDL_crop, "EPSG:4326")
   #The command below takes a few minutes to run (maybe 5-10 minutes with one core)
ST_CDL_crop_buffer <- terra::buffer(ST_CDL_crop, 500)
   #As mentioned previously not I get the error message below whenever I try to run
   #terra::buffer(), terra::as.polygons(), or terra::is.valid() on ST_CDL_crop_buffer
   #Error: IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1 elements
   #To reproduce that, just run the code below
#Intersect buffer and natural landscapes
intersection <- terra::intersect(ST_CDL_crop_buffer, ST_CDL_nat_lands)
```

UPDATE:
A friend ran my code and got a different (though similar) error message. It is: `Error: TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Nested shells at -120.40542544090771 34.654180422003208` . I am still unsure how to deal with it.

Comment: "OpenET" is not defined.

Comment: @RobertHijmans, sorry, I have edited the code and it should be fine now. I have excluded the mention to OpenET.